# Https in java ends up with strange results

Tags: java, http, https

I'm trying to illustrate to students how **https** is used in java. But i have the feeling my example is not really the best out there...

The code works well on my windows 7: I start the server, go to **https**://localhost:8080/somefile.txt and i get asked to trust the certificate, and all goes well.
When I try over **http** (before or after accepting the certificate) I just get a blank page, which is ok for me.

BUT when I try the exact same thing on my windows XP: Same thing, all goes well. But then (after accepting the certificate first), I'm also able to get all the the files through **http**! (if I first try **http** before **https** followed by accepting the certificate, I get no answer..)

I tried refreshing, hard refreshing a million times but this should not be working, right?

Is there something wrong in my code? I'm not sure if I use the right approach to implement https here...

```
package Security;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.security.*;

import javax.net.ssl.*;

import com.sun.net.httpserver.*;


public class HTTPSServer 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
    {
        InetSocketAddress addr = new InetSocketAddress(8080);
        HttpsServer server = HttpsServer.create(addr, 0);

        try
        {
            System.out.println("\nInitializing context ...\n");
            KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
            char[] password = "vwpolo".toCharArray();
            ks.load(new FileInputStream("myKeys"), password);
            KeyManagerFactory kmf = KeyManagerFactory.getInstance("SunX509");
            kmf.init(ks, password);
            SSLContext sslContext = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
            sslContext.init(kmf.getKeyManagers(), null, null);

            //  a HTTPS server must have a configurator for the SSL connections.
            server.setHttpsConfigurator (new HttpsConfigurator(sslContext)
            {
                //  override configure to change default configuration.
                public void configure (HttpsParameters params)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        //  get SSL context for this configurator
                        SSLContext c = getSSLContext();

                        //  get the default settings for this SSL context
                        SSLParameters sslparams = c.getDefaultSSLParameters();

                        //  set parameters for the HTTPS connection.
                        params.setNeedClientAuth(true);
                        params.setSSLParameters(sslparams);
                        System.out.println("SSL context created ...\n");
                    }
                    catch(Exception e2)
                    {
                        System.out.println("Invalid parameter ...\n");
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        catch(Exception e1)
        {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }

        server.createContext("/", new MyHandler1());
        server.setExecutor(Executors.newCachedThreadPool());
        server.start();
        System.out.println("Server is listening on port 8080 ...\n");
    }
}

class MyHandler implements HttpHandler 
{
    public void handle(HttpExchange exchange) throws IOException
    {
        String requestMethod = exchange.getRequestMethod();
        if (requestMethod.equalsIgnoreCase("GET"))
        {
            Headers responseHeaders = exchange.getResponseHeaders();
            responseHeaders.set("Content-Type", "text/plain");
            exchange.sendResponseHeaders(200, 0);

            OutputStream responseBody = exchange.getResponseBody();
            String response = "HTTP headers included in your request:\n\n";
            responseBody.write(response.getBytes());

            Headers requestHeaders = exchange.getRequestHeaders();
            Set<String> keySet = requestHeaders.keySet();
            Iterator<String> iter = keySet.iterator();
            while (iter.hasNext())
            {
                String key = iter.next();
                List values = requestHeaders.get(key);
                response = key + " = " + values.toString() + "\n";
                responseBody.write(response.getBytes());
                System.out.print(response);
            }

            response = "\nHTTP request body: ";
            responseBody.write(response.getBytes());
            InputStream requestBody = exchange.getRequestBody();
            byte[] buffer = new byte[256];
            if(requestBody.read(buffer) > 0) 
            {
                responseBody.write(buffer);
            }
            else
            {
                responseBody.write("empty.".getBytes());
            }

            URI requestURI = exchange.getRequestURI();
            String file = requestURI.getPath().substring(1);
            response = "\n\nFile requested = " + file + "\n\n";
            responseBody.write(response.getBytes());
            responseBody.flush();
            System.out.print(response);

            Scanner source = new Scanner(new File(file));
            String text;
            while (source.hasNext())
            {
                text = source.nextLine() + "\n";
                responseBody.write(text.getBytes());
            }
            source.close();

            responseBody.close();

            exchange.close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This sounds like a browser issue.  What browser version are you using?

Comment: I don't see any code where you're checking whether the connection is secured or not. As such, you're relying on some default in the API you're using and in that browser to do what you want. Its a much better idea to check for yourself if the connection is secured or not, or disable non-SSL connections.

Comment: I've been thinking about that too, (in a different example with just an SSL server, I tried some different (SSL, non-SSL) clients; the server accepted the connection, but just crashed afterwards)
How exactly can I check if the connection is secured? (or how do you disable non-SSL connections?)

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to make a demonstration to your students, then I'd suggest to avoid the bells and whistles of a full-blown HTTP server running.

I'd have just a `SSLServerSocket` serving a default HTML page whenever a secured connection is successfully made.